# How to create Background Process Application in Windows?

Tags: wpf, windows, assembly, service, process

I developed one chat-based Application like Skype. Once I opened that application I get to receive the message after I closed that application I can't get messages. So I Move on Background Process on my Application when system startup it also runs behind. 
 Guide me it Possible?

Regards
Dinesh D

Comment: Applications like Skype were started **minimized** at login. That is the whole magic. There is no such thing like a "background process"

Comment: once I installed that application particular system I hardcoded Login Details for that system.

Comment: Do you want to talk about starting an application at startup or how to store login details?

Comment: I also startup functions also are done in my WPF code. the only thing it only runs on a background process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is using tray icon application and timer that will check your messages every X minutes.

So the application won't be closed but only tray icon will be shown only in a tray area (application windows should be hidden - it needs to implement it on close button instead of exit from application, for example). And timer will work and receive messages while the application is not closed from the tray.

To implement tray icon in WPF you can use Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf and Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification packages from nuget. You also can show popups from tray using this packages.

Comment: thank you @AnnaS It's Working Sorry for the delay response.